# Pandas dataframe get expanding/rolling value counts

Tags: python, pandas, series, rolling-computation

Is it possible to create value counts for a series in a cumulative/expanding fashion? E.g. for the following series

`pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'])`

I'd want

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c'
   1,   0,  0
   2,   0,   0 
   2,   1,   0
   2,   1,   1
   2,   1,   2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Encode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) the series into indicator variables and use `cumsum`

```
s.str.get_dummies().cumsum()
```

---

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  2  0  0
2  2  1  0
3  2  1  1
4  2  1  2
```